# Content in my local resource files seems to be cached

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I have a webpage where I uses the App_LocalResources files, where I've translations for 2 languages.

This works really well. However, when I open my two pages I get a pretty strange problem. If I open the English version, my Danish URL is also English. If I open med Danish URL first, the English one is in Danish. If i CTRL+F5 it, it changes language.

You can see the result here:

- http://www.btcglobe.com/buybtc.aspx (English version)
- http://www.btcglobe.com/buybtc/da (Danish version)

This is really annoying, as it should load the appropriate language right away.

My code on the butbtc.aspx page is (I have also tried Page_Load):

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    SetupLanguage();

}
```

My SetupLanguage method is:

```
private void SetupLanguage()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentLanguage))
        {
            if (CurrentLanguage == "da")
            {
                CultureInfo dkinfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-dk");
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = dkinfo;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = dkinfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = dkinfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = dkinfo;

                Page.Title = GetLocalResourceObject("PageTitleString").ToString();
                return;
            }
        }
        CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = info;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = info;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;

    }
```

My CurrentLanguage property is defined like this:

```
 public string CurrentLanguage
    {
        get
        {
            var toolValue = Page.RouteData.Values["language"];
            if (toolValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toolValue.ToString()))
            {
                return toolValue.ToString();
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

If my route has any meaning, it is:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("Buy Bitcoins",
                        "buybtc/{language}",
                        "~/buybtc.aspx");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to override InitializeCulture such as:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    SetupLanguage();
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

This is called earlier in the page lifecycle. See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: Now, that just solved sooo many hours of work. Thanks so much :)